# ContextMenu Checkable menuitem not working

Tags: xaml

Here is my code

```
<UserControl.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=btnSearch,Path=IsChecked}" Header="Search"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.ContextMenu>

       <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >           
                <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonAnchor}"  Content="Search" x:Name="btnSearch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

<Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=btnSearch, Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</Grid>
```

I want to change the visibility of Last grid using toggled button checked changed, its working but how can include Menu Item checked also changing last grid visibility.

Comment: What do you mean? Please clarify your answer. You want when two of the controls are checked than hide the last grid or when one of the controls checked the other one would be checked too and then hide the grid?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to change this grid's visibility when both of them checked or either one of them checked. I think best way to go here to cover both cases since you did not clarify what you want is to go with Multiple Binding.
Here is my implementation when I hide the grid when both of them is checked buth it is easili changable.

First thing first we will need a View.

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <MenuItem
            Name="test"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Header="Search"
            IsCheckable="True"
            IsChecked="False" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <ToggleButton Content="Search" x:Name="btnSearch" IsChecked="False" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="btnSearch" Path="IsChecked" />
                    <Binding ElementName="test" Path="IsChecked" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Visibility>

            <TextBlock Text="tralala" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

After the view we will need a converter. In our case BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values != null)
            {
                bool btnSerach = bool.Parse(values[0].ToString());
                bool menuItemTest = bool.Parse(values[1].ToString());

                if (btnSerach && menuItemTest)
                    return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }

            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You can easily change or extend the code for your needs. Hope this helps.